# Eclipse removing white spaces when saving

Tags: eclipse, configuration, formatting, eclipse-neon, reformatting

I have a big issue. I develop in eclipse ide environment, mostly on windows but also on linux. This seems to be a general issue.
Before I save my project on eclipse I have certain spaces between functions or in the code somewhere. I don't want to reformat the code that is in place.
However, every single time I try to save my project. Those spaces disappear, and I cannot find the place where I should change this auto-formatting in my eclipse properties.
Please see example bellow:

First of all I don't touch the code but I receive it as bellow and have to make modifications elsewhere. So at the initial state of my file I have somewhere in the code two functions [functionOne, functionTwo]. Those two functions are separated by a new line [NL] and 6 spaces. The problem appears when I save my project and as you can see the two functions are not separated anymore by the same number of spaces.

> Before saving my project:

```
     public void functionOne(){
         int i = 0;
         while(i<150)
         {
            //blabla...
         }
     }
```

NL:***123456***

```
     public void functionTwo(){
         int i = 0;
         while(i<150)
         {
            //blabla...
         }
     }
```

> After saving my project:

```
     public void functionOne(){
         int i = 0;
         while(i<150)
         {
            //blabla...
         }
     }
```

NL:***1***

```
     public void functionTwo(){
         int i = 0;
         while(i<150)
         {
            //blabla...
         }
     }
```

I'm starting to be sick of this issue and really need help to solve this.
Not forgetting to mention that absolutely no "Save actions" is enabled!
I don't see anything on my format options neither, but I could be wrong. 
Could someone please help me to find a solutions to this problem?

Best regards,
Greg

Comment: Save actions can be configured in two places - the project properties, and the main preferences - have you checked both.

Comment: Hi, yes I did check!

Comment: @Greg86 are you using any custom format style in your eclipse IDE?

Comment: @Yogesh Only default setup...

Comment: Are you sure you disabled _Save Actions_ (see @greg-449's comment): right-click project: _Properties: Java Editor > Save Actions:_ enable project specific settings and disable _Perform the selected actions on save_. Also [AnyEdit](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/anyedit-tools) can remove whitespace on save.

Comment: Yes, it was AnyEdit removing whitespace for me. I like the plugin, but that was a sneaky gotcha.

Answer (score 1):

So that wasn't the "Save actions" but some plugin that I was using. Didn't had the time to check which one it is I just uninstalled the rarely/unused once. And for the moment it seems to work. I'll check later if the problem remains/reappears.

Thanks for your help.
Best regards,
Gregory